# Как правильно вывести массив (char)?

Tags: c++, массивы, строки, visual-studio-2017

Нужно вывести массив из 20ти q. Но он вместо этого выводит: `qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqММММT?HЎhэУ`. Как это исправить?

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "rus");
char tt[20] = { 'q', 'q', 'q', 'q', 'q', 'q', 'q', 'q', 'q', 'q', 'q', 'q', 'q', 'q', 'q', 'q', 'q', 'q', 'q', 'q' };
cout << tt << endl;
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Судя по разнообразию ответов, надо тэг code-golf добавлять :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Строка в стиле С (массив `char`) должна завершаться нулевым символом.

Вариант 1.

```
char tt[21] = { 'q', 'q', 'q', 'q', 'q', 'q', 'q', 'q', 'q', 'q',
                'q', 'q', 'q', 'q', 'q', 'q', 'q', 'q', 'q', 'q', '\0' };
```

Вариант 2.

```
for(auto c: q) cout << c; cout << endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

Используйте `std::string_view`

```
  #include <iterator>
  #include <string_view>
  ...
  char tt[20] = { ... };
  std::cout << std::string_view(tt, std::size(tt)) << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 #include <cstdlib>
 #include<iostream>
 using namespace std;
 int main(){
 char chr[90] = "q q qq q q";//объявили массив символов и проинициализировали
 cout << chr;
 return 0;
}
```

Добавляйте столько q сколько нужно

Answer (score 1):

И я хочу поучаствовать! :)

```
copy(begin(tt),endd(tt), std::ostream_iterator<char>(cout,""));
```

и

```
cout << string(begin(tt),end(tt));
```